# Can ANYONE add a service reference to my web service?

Tags: web-services

Im new to working with web services, but if I create a web service in visual studio then deploy it, can't anyone who finds the link just add a service reference to it and use it?

Comment: If it's publicly accessible and doesn't require authentication/authorization of some kind, then yes.  Anything you put on the internet is, well, on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

That's why you should secure web services that should not be available to the public.  Many web services use an API key and/or password to secure access.  You can also restrict access to specific IP addresses, depending on your situation.